# Node.js video chat application

Tags: node.js, web-applications, video, chat

How would you implement a video chat application using node.js?

Any resources(tutorials, books, links) or a general gameplan/strategy would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about central server handling viedo chat? I suggest not doing it at all and do P2P.

Comment: I haven't built a video chat application before so I don't know the 'preferred' method of implementation, generally looking to create a video chat application that will allow people to communicate over the web

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @freakish do you know how facebook is doing it? Is fb using server to handle it OR p2p ?

Comment: @Oucam not sure. But most likely they use servers to some degree. You know, permanent invigilation matters more to those people.

Comment: A good one: https://youtu.be/ieBtXwHvoNk

Answer (score 12):

Right now there are two Node.js projects for video chat. Both are experimental, but I've heard they work quite well if you can get them running.

https://github.com/webRTC/webrtc.io-client => The current champ for chat.

https://github.com/kdomagal/Web-RTC => Only a demo app

Answer (score 7):

There is a Project that aims at these sorts of problems (http://www.webrtc.org/). I would probably stream the video to the server and then to the client, or wait til the P2P API is ready and then implement a P2P version if you have time to wait.

Comment: is there a huge difference in both implementations(streaming to server then client vs. using P2P?)
Generally I'm looking to create a video chat application using node.js that will allow people to communicate over the web

Comment: Yes, there is. Sending audio+video data over internet is quite heavy. Central server won't ever scale well. Unless number of users is limited per server.

Comment: Good point, do you know how most people implement a video chat application in order to have a MVP(minimum viable product)

Comment: @user90500 did you ever come up with an MVP for this?

Comment: @emilebaizel yeh this tutorial should help get you started:
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/getting-started-with-opentok-from-0-to-simple-group-video-chat/